# parent nodes value to be the sum of all its childrens

Tags: javascript, c#, recursion, tree

I've an edit tree (can change the value of the node) that isn't a binary tree, I want to store the sum of nodes values in the parent node.
i.e:

```
   50
/   |   \
10  25  15
|   | \   |  \
10  3 22  10  5
```

in the editing I success to change all the hierarchy, but the initialize I don't succeeded, for example I've just the values of the deepest level (10  3 22  10  5), Then want to start from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My strategy was to do a top-down traversal.  Leaf nodes simply return their current value.  Internal nodes recompute based on the sum of their children.

```
function initialize(node) {
    // internal nodes get their total from children
    if (node.children.length > 0) {
        node.value = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            node.value += initialize(node.children[i]);
        }
    }
    return node.value;
}
initialize(root);
```

Comment: I'd redommend not modifying the input in the process, these kinds of side effects are unclean. Just return the accumulated `value` directly.

Answer (score 0):

try to update the parent node values using child node values, for example

```
Node node = //get the changed node
while (node.Parent != null)
{
    node = node.Parent;
    // set node.Value from sum of node.childnode values 
}
```